Flutter InAppWebView PrintJobSetting is not applying settings on printing
I have added this code in onPrintRequest in InAppWebViewSettings. But those settings that I have provided in PrintJobSettings are not applying in generated documents. And in print preview it is not showing A4 paper size.
I am using InAppWebView 6.0.0 for my project.
onPrintRequest: (controller, url, printJobController) async {
            printJobController?.dispose();

            PrintJobSettings settings = PrintJobSettings(
                handledByClient: true,
                jobName:
                    "${await webViewController?.getTitle() ?? ''} - PDF Document example",
                colorMode: PrintJobColorMode.MONOCHROME,
                outputType: PrintJobOutputType.GRAYSCALE,
                orientation: PrintJobOrientation.PORTRAIT,
                margins: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                mediaSize: PrintJobMediaSize(
                    heightMils: 292,
                    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
                    widthMils: 210),
                numberOfPages: 1);
            print('printing');
            await controller.printCurrentPage(settings: settings);
            return true;
          },

I was expecting to apply those settings on generated documents.
